# How to make each new line into a list in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list

For example, say I have an object that looks like this:

```
data {
    second minute hour
    dog cat horse
    apple orange strawberry
}
```

How would I parse through the fields{} dict and turn each line into it's own array/list.
I want my output to look like this:

```
data {
    [one: second, two: minute, three: hour]
    [one: dog, two: cat, three: horse]
    [one: apple, two: orange, three: strawberry]
}
```

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: In Python, it's a dict. In JS, it's called an object.

Comment: These aren't valid javascript, you'll need to edit if you want meaningful answers

Comment: Is that an object or array, actually?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split()`:

```js
const data = [
    "second minute hour",
    "dog cat horse",
    "apple orange strawberry"
];
let result = [];
data.forEach(item => {
  let s = item.split(" ");
  result.push({
    one: s[0],
    two: s[1],
    three: s[2]
  });
});
console.log("Full result:", result);
console.log("More specific:", result[2].two);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with the Syntax you wrote but it is possible if you wrap your data obj as a string ! ( use template strings as you can pass variables with it too)

See =>

```
const orange = "orange";

let data = ` {
second minute hour
dog cat horse
apple ${orange} strawberry
}`;

data = data.replaceAll('{', "");
data = data.replaceAll('}', "");
data = data.trim().split('\n');


let final_data = {};
data.forEach((val, index) =>  final_data[index] = val.trim().split(' '));
data = final_data;
final_data = {};
console.log(data);
```